# Overriding methods with the same name

Tags: java

So I have these two classes:

Parent

```
public class MyClass {
    protected int myVal;
    public MyClass(int val) {
        setMyVal(val);
    }
    private void setMyVal(int val) {
        myVal = val;
    }
}
```

Child

```
public class SubClass extends MyClass {
    public SubClass(int val) {
        super(val);
    }

    private void setMyVal(int val) {
        myVal = val + 1;
    }
}
```

Which `setMyVal` will be called when a child class is created?

I have a lot of child classes that need to have their `myVal` set with different logic, including the parent class.

So for instance, if I make a parent class instance it will need to simply set `myVal` to the `val` passed in. If a child class instance is created it will need to set `myVal` in a completely different way, and have nothing to do with the way the parent class `myVal` is set. Is this the correct way to do this?

Comment: Private methods **aren't** inherited. Make them `protected` if you want `SubClass`, if they're `private` then you get the one from `MyClass`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to Java and the entire concept of visibility to be honest. Should both the parent and child method be protected? Or should the parent be protected, and the child public?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch above

Answer (score 1):

The child class or `SubClass` is going to override any method(apart from `private` ones) coming from the parent class, most popular one is `toString` where every class extends `Object` which contains `toString()` method, but the one implemented in your child class is the one that gets called.

According to App Shah in [Cruchify](http://crunchify.com/), he gave some nice rules to note when overriding methods [here](http://crunchify.com/java-method-overriding-examples-and-concepts-overriding-rules/)

> Rules for method overriding:
>
> In java, a method can only be written in Subclass, not in same class.
>
> The argument list should be exactly the same as that of the overridden
> method.
>
> The return type should be the same or a subtype of the return
> type declared in the original overridden method in the super class.
>
> The access level cannot be more restrictive than the overridden
> method’s access level. For example: if the super class method is
> declared public then the overridding method in the sub class cannot be
> either private or protected.
>
> Instance methods can be overridden only
> if they are inherited by the subclass.
>
> A method declared final cannot
> be overridden.
>
> A method declared static cannot be overridden but can
> be re-declared.
>
> If a method cannot be inherited then it cannot be
> overridden.

[Read more](http://crunchify.com/java-method-overriding-examples-and-concepts-overriding-rules/) Few rules with examples, so you understand it and hopes it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Private method is not inherited. If you want to override method of existing method of parent class, please use public or protected.

In case of overriding, method of subclass is called. This explains how polymorphism comes to work.
You can define many different classes inheriting same interface(or abstract class). They have different implementation details, but can be operated using same interface.

Answer (score -2):

First of you don't need to call the `setValue(val)` in the constructor of the parent class
the best way to create your constructor is with the parameter:

```
public MyClass(int val) {
this.myVal = val;
}
```

if want the behavior of a method to be different in a subclass, you need to override it:

```
@Override
protected void setValue(int val){
myVal = val + 1;
}
```

also make the methods protected instead of private

I hope this helps